# Useful projects in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am very sorry if I ask a wrong question but I really need a professional help. I have to make a rather complex project for a begginer, using Visual Haskell, for a course of functional programming. The problem is that because I am at the beginning I don't know what kind of theme to pick. I want to make a project that evidentiates the real utility of functional programming. If you could just give me some ideas I will be very grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Has the teacher given any other guidelines?

Comment: No he didn't give us any other guidelines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> want to make a project that
>   evidentiates the real utility of
>   functional programming. If you could
>   just give me some ideas I will be very
>   grateful.

Alright, then let me tell you something. Programming is about expression. Functional languages let you express things differently. What are the benefits of the expressions made possible with functional programming?

Infinite lists and recursion can be expressed very simple.

Recursion is functional programming done right.

Try to implement algorithms and datastructures that use it. Balanced trees, fibonacci, euclidian algorithm, all that will benefit from it. Really, anything that features a tree can be expressed very elegantly in functional languages.

Give mathetmical problems a try, try to solve the [Euler Problems](http://projecteuler.net/) with Haskell.

Comment: Infinite lists example: `fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)`. Best fibonacci implementation ever.

Comment: @delnan: Better use @-Patterns... ;)

Comment: @FUZxxl: Why did you downrate me, please explain.

Answer (score 5):

You could design a simple programming language and write an interpreter for it:
Check the tools Alex (http://www.haskell.org/alex/) for lexical analysis, and happy (http://www.haskell.org/happy/) for parsing your code.

You can make the language as complex as you want. I think that defining While loops and functions could make it sufficiently complex and satisfying for a beginner.

Comment: Parsec is pretty usable, too.

Comment: Three cheers for parsec.  Haskell is too powerful to need a parser generator.